# Bootstrap panel sorting by dates with php

Tags: php, sorting, twitter-bootstrap-3, panels

I'm building php mysql app for job interviews, and I want to have for admin filer with bootstrap panels which are sorted by date in the same color column.

```
$db = connectPDO();
   $query = ("SELECT razgovori.*, djelatnik.ime, djelatnik.prezime
        FROM razgovori INNER JOIN djelatnik 
        ON djelatnik.id = razgovori.insert_by 
        ORDER BY datum_raz ASC");

  $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
  $stmt->execute();
  $count = $stmt->rowCount();
  $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $date = strtotime($row['datum_raz']);
  $twoDaysAgoStart =  strtotime('-2 day 00:00:00');
  $yesterdayEnd =  strtotime('yesterday 23:59:59');
  $todayStart = strtotime('today 00:00:00');    
  $todayEnd = strtotime('today 23:59:59');  
  $tomorrowStart =  strtotime('tomorrow 00:00:00'); 
  $twoDaysAheadEnd =  strtotime('+2 day 23:59:59');

   <div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)): ?>

     <?php $date = strtotime($row['datum_raz']); ?>   

    <?php if ($twoDaysAgoStart < $date && $yesterdayEnd > $date): ?> 

  <!--Panel info if past time Job interviews-->
  <div class="col-md-4 pull-left">
   <div class="panel panel-info">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo 
     datumVrijemeSQLuHR($row['datum_raz']); ?></h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-md-9">
        <h5><a href="editRazgovori.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php 
         echo $row['rime'].' '.$row['rprezime']; ?></a></h5>           
          <?php echo $row['kontakt_br']; ?>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <span class="label label-default pull-right"></h5><?php echo 
    $row['ime'].' '.$row['prezime']; ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
<!--//Panel--> 
</tr>
<tr>
<!--Panel primary if Job interview is today-->
<?php elseif ($todayStart <= $date && $todayEnd >= $date): ?>  
 <div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo 
datumVrijemeSQLuHR($row['datum_raz']); ?></h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
   <div class="col-md-9">
    <h5><a href="editRazgovori.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php echo 
$row['rime'].' '.$row['rprezime']; ?></a></h5>           
        <?php echo $row['kontakt_br']; ?>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <span class="label label-default pull-right"></h5><?php echo 
$row['ime'].' '.$row['prezime']; ?></span>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>      
</div>
</tr>
<tr>
<!--Panel warning if Job interview is tomorrow-->
<?php  elseif ($tomorrowStart <= $date && $twoDaysAheadEnd >= $date): ?>   
 <div class="col-md-4 pull-right">
  <div class="panel panel-warning">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h3 class="panel-title"><?php echo 
        datumVrijemeSQLuHR($row['datum_raz']); ?></h3></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-md-9">
      <h5><a href="editRazgovori.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><?php 
        echo $row['rime'].' '.$row['rprezime']; ?></a></h5>           
          <?php echo $row['kontakt_br']; ?>
        </div>
          <div class="col-md-3">
              <span class="label label-default pull-right"></h5><?php echo 
                      $row['ime'].' '.$row['prezime']; ?></span>
            </div>

        </div>
      </div>      
      </div>
     <?php endif; ?>


    <?php endwhile; ?> 

  </div><!--/row-->
</div><!--/container-->
```

[I want to have sorted like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5K0sh.png)with Main Panal or without

I get this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5kDS.png)

Because stackoverflow red message constantly asking me for more details, i can't put my all php code

Comment: What have you tried to change the order?

Comment: Hi Vedran, ive added an answer. Please let me know if this was any helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in your MySQL query.

**Example:**

```
SELECT * FROM t1
  ORDER BY key_part1, key_part2;

SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE key_part1 = constant
  ORDER BY key_part2;

SELECT * FROM t1
  ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 DESC;

SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE key_part1 = 1
  ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 DESC;

SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE key_part1 > constant
  ORDER BY key_part1 ASC;

SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE key_part1 < constant
  ORDER BY key_part1 DESC;

SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE key_part1 = constant1 AND key_part2 > constant2
  ORDER BY key_part2;
```

More information can be found here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html or https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

**If you want to do this inside `PHP` you can use sort:**

```
<?php

$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana", "apple");
sort($fruits);
foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
    echo "fruits[" . $key . "] = " . $val . "\n";
}

?>
```

**The above example will output:**

> fruits[0] = apple fruits[1] = banana fruits[2] = lemon fruits[3] =
>   orange

More information about `PHP` `sort()`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

Comment: Thank you for fast answer, but that is not what i looking for. I think it is more complex solution. Im already fetching all rows from database. I wanna have ordered panels by dates in three columns with main panel or without main panel

Comment: In that case you need to use a very smart foreach inside a foreach. Try to find another, cleaner, solutions for this situation. It could be a pain in the ass. When ever I have a foreach in a foreach, I try to create extra arrays.